# phrase as alternative to "I'm scared of being here"?

Tags: american-english, british-english, learning

I want to know if I could strike a more formal tone as an alternative to "I'm scared of being here" like:

1 - "I'm in fear to be here"

or "I'm feared to be here"

are those acceptable English?

Comment: Most people would say none of those, including the first, and would probably say 'being here scares me'.

Answer (score 1):

"A formal tone" seems inappropriate to the context - which is someone speaking without preparation, about their feelings, in an emotional state.

That said, there are lots of words in English surrounding this emotion.  You can use scare as a verb "Being here scares me", or as an adjective "This place is scary".  You can make yourself the subject "I'm scared of this place", "I'm feeling scared to be here".

You can use "afraid".  "I'm afraid of being here".  "This place is making me feel afraid".  There is little difference in meaning or formality between "feel scared" and "feel afraid".

Let's look at some more formal expressions with "fear" in the past tense: "I felt fear in that place". "I was in fear for my life to be there".  Using the noun "fear" is a little more formal. So more appropriate to a past tense sentence, looking back at a situation when you are no longer afraid.